# How to read a JSON file through Informatica using java transformation

Tags: json, transformation, etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have one JASON file which I want to use as source.What is the way I can read it through Informatica using Java Transformation?

Comment: Please let us know where exactly you are facing problem?

Comment: I have a json file.I want to read the data inside the file and convert that data in csv format through informatica

Comment: how large do you expect the json file to be? if small, then you could load the content as a text field on SQ and push it over to a java transformation.

Comment: The json file is not very large.but what will be the code in the java transformation???I am not able to fetch the contents inside the json file dynamically

Comment: I do not think you can read JSON file using informatica java transformation. You need special B2B Data Transformation tool. I recomend, use some java code to read your file and generate a csv file out of it. Run that as pre-process and then use informatica.

Answer (score 0):

Load the JSON file using a JAVA transformation. To accomplish this I have used [GSON](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/) and [Jackson](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-2-convert-java-object-to-from-json/) before.

You can then assign the data you need from the JSON objects into output ports, generate rows, and continue with your processing.